# All square integrable (in ${\mathbb R}$) entire functions are Schwartz?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...$ be entire function and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^2 dx < \infty$. Is it true that $f\in {\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$?

Comment: No: $f(x)=\frac {\sin x} x$ for $x \neq 0, f(0)=1$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed simple!